# what would cause an http server to respond to different clients with a different version of the http protocol?

Tags: http

I've got a strange problem.  I'm sending an HTTP GET request to a webserver embedded in a modem on my local network (the embedded webserver is the interface to the "control panel" for the modem).  When the request is sent from my desktop machine or my phone the server responds with an HTTP/1.0 response.  However, when I send the request from my laptop the server responds with an HTTP/0.9.  The problem is that the embedded webserver's implementation of HTTP/0.9 is buggy such that the response headers are screwed up and hence, the client can't understand the response (the headers are part of the response body).  This behavior happens regardless of the client used to send the request.  So, my question is: what would cause the embedded webserver to respond with a different HTTP version?

Here are the particulars:

- modem: HughesNet HN7000S
- embedded webserver: WindWeb/1.0
- desktop OS: Vista 64 Home Premium/SP2
- phone OS: Android 2.3.4
- laptop OS: Win7 Home Premium/SP1
- desktop clients: FireFox v13.0.1, IE8, and a perl command-line client (implemented with the standard LWP and HTTP perl modules
- phone clients: FireFox v14.0 and stock Android Browser
- laptop clients: Firefox v13.0.1, IE9 and the same perl command-line client as for the desktop
- desktop connection to modem: ethernet direct to modem, ethernet thru wireless router
  phone connection to modem: via wireless
- laptop connection to modem: ethernet direct to modem, ethernet thru wireless router, wireless

[note: I don't get a cell signal at my home and so can't try the phone over a data connection]

I've tried forcing the IP addresses for the desktop and laptop to be the same (obviously, disconnecting one or the other in the process) in case somehow the embedded webserver was keying off the IP address of the incoming request to determine what version of HTTP to respond with.

Of course, I got absolutely nowhere with HughesNet technical support.  I've tried looking on the web for documentation on the WindWeb embedded webserver but haven't found anything.

The laptop has no problem getting a "reasonable" response back from any other webserver...so I'm inclined to think the problem is with the embedded webserver in the modem.  But since the embedded webserver responding with the buggy HTTP/0.9 response only seems to happen when the request is sent from my laptop and it happens regardless of the client the request is sent from on the laptop I have to think the problem has something to do with some network setting on the laptop but I can't imagine what setting would affect the version of HTTP the embedded server responds with.

Can anyone help out?  Either with a direct solution or with other things I should check for?  Is there any other info about the 3 machines, their connectivity or anything else that would be helpful in diagnosing the problem?

Comment: one other thing I've tried: connecting to the embedded webserver via telnet from the desktop & laptop and directly issuing the HTTP request (e.g., typing `GET / HTTP/1.1`).  In the case of the desktop I get a valid HTTP/1.0 response.  From the laptop I get a 400 "Bad Request" response (but again, it's an HTTP/0.9 response with the same bug in tha tthe headers aren't formatted corrected)

Comment: Use wireshark to capture the HTTP requests and compare them.

Comment: @nos: I installed wireshark on both the desktop and laptop.  Did a capture on each for requests send with both FF v13.0.1 and the perl command-line client.

Using FF, the requests are identical between the desktop and the laptop except for the User-Agent header (diff in the OS portion of the string).

Using the perl command-line client on the desktop and laptop, the requests are identical.

The odd thing is that WireShark seems to think the responses on the laptop are HTTP/1.0.  The reason I know they are actually HTTP/0.9 is by having the perl client output $response->protocol.

Comment: No need to install wireshark. It's as simple as `nc -l -p 8080` to run a webserver on the console which prints out the next request received at port 8080

Answer (score 0):

Most clients send a client string to identify itself, like `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.1.16) Gecko/20120602 Iceweasel/3.5.16 (like Firefox/3.5.16)`. This is used by some broken servers to adapt the content. For example, my uni's file server wouldn't let me download some css files with wget (which is hilarious) unless I called wget with `-U ""` to not send an empty clientstring.

Comment: As mentioned, I've tried with FF v13, IE8 and a command-line client...all of which use a non-empty User-Agent string.

Comment: As you see, the client string does not only contain the browser make, but also its version, and information about the client machine aswell. I bet that's what makes the difference.

Comment: Can you explain WHY you think it is making a difference?

Comment: I can tell from experience, as I've said in my answer.